# Omitting articles when contrasting people or things with "and"

Tags: grammar, articles

There's a rule that says articles can be omitted when nouns referring to two contrasting people or things are joined by 'and'.

> The independent allowances for **husband and wife** will both be
>   available.
>
> ...the natural relationship between **father and son**.
>
> In a formal sense, the main difference between **teacher** and **student** is the amount of education.
>
> ...as the distinctions between **employer** and **employee** are
>   gradually eroded.
>
> ...with little gardens between **river** and **road**.
>
> There was a pause, and **doctor** and **patient** looked steadily at each
>   other across the quiet room.

Does the same principle apply to nouns that by default have the definite article? If so, are the sentences below correct? Why is the definite article in sentence 3 omitted in the phrase "whereas for past tense"? Shouldn't it be "the past tense"? Is the definite article in "past tense" omitted because there's also an element of contrast?

> 1. The relation between the sexes has always found its cosmic expression
>      in the relation between **moon** and **sun**. (I'm talking about the earth's moon and sun)
> 2. Even as the French king was hatching plans to destroy and annihilate a nascent coexistence between **English language** and
>      English national identity, the supremacy of French culture was
>      preserved by the language in which late medieval England conducted its
>      official business. (Can the definite article in "English language" be omitted?)
> 3. For English, Huddleston and Pullum (2002: 143) point out that the difference between **present perfect** and **past tense** is that in
>      the present perfect the primary focus is on the present moment,
>      whereas for **past tense** it is on the past.

Comment: Sun and moon may be different because there's only one. Yet, the sentence I just wrote without articles seems fine, so I guess you can leave off the article. To me what sounds more odd is saying moon first.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, all nouns are 'by default' definite unless they are given an indefinite determiner.  That is why we can omit definite articles in front of names, titles, and crowded nouns (on signs, such as '[the] door' in: "keep door shut").

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that you can drop the 'the' anytime, but the default really is definite.  This also applies to personal destinations, like 'home', 'school', 'church' and 'town'.